# What's the meaning of tangent in the velocity panel in the particle settings?

Tags: physics, particles

I wish to know the meaning of the "tangent" option available in particles panel; for a surface in 3D, tangent means a surface. But velocity is a linear, directional entity.

I am currently working on a project which involves emission of particles along the slope of a cone.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly, 'tangent' means a vector that touches the surface at precisely one point. Not the surface itself. So in the particle setting context:

`tangent` controls the starting force that is applied to the particle *parallel* to the emitter surface.

`Normal` controls the force that is applied to the particle *perpendicular* to the emitter surface.

To put it another way,

tangent = 1, normal = 0 will make the particle emit 'sideways'.

tangent = 0, normal = 1 will make the particle emit 'out'.

tangent = 1, normal = 1 will make the particle emit at 45degrees to the surface.

Comment: What if the emitting surface is a plane? All directions are parallel to the surface. In that case what will be the direction of the velocity of the particles emitted, if the tangent value is 1 ?

Comment: Then the direction of the velocity depends on the `Rotation` value underneath is. Try it out with a simple particle system (best to turn off gravity to see things more clearly)

Comment: I tried that too...for a plane I couldn't observe any rotation at all...when the ROT value was increased above 0.5, then the velocity direction simply became opposite. But I was not able to fix/find the direction of the initial tangential velocity.